# How get clicked item in vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm trying to do basic something but i can't figure out.

i have a dropdown:

```
<div class="dropdown is-active">
  <div class="dropdown-trigger">
    <button class="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-controls="dropdown-menu">
      <span>{{selectedItem}}</span>
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="dropdown-menu" id="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
    <div class="dropdown-content" v-model="selectedItem">
      <a class="dropdown-item" v-for="item in items">
        {{item.name}}
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    selectedItem: null,
     items: [
     {
         name: "Dropdown Item"
     },
     {
         name: "Dropdown Item 2"
     },
     {
         name: "Dropdown Item 3"
     }
    ]
  },
});
```

Basically i'm trying to do when clicked to dropdown item it will be {{selectedItem}} for that i have tried to use v-model in my menu wrapper but nothing happened.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You cannot use `v-model` with `div` here.

Instead, You should use `v-click` to call a method in order to update value `selectedItem` and handle toggle action.

One more thing, When you use `v-for` you should have `key id` which is recommended by Vuejs.

Just draft implementation:

```
<div class="dropdown is-active">
  <div class="dropdown-trigger">
    <button class="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-controls="dropdown-menu">
      <span>{{selectedItem}}</span>
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="dropdown-menu" id="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a class="dropdown-item" v-for="item in items" :key="item.id" v-click="handleSelectItem(item)">
        {{item.name}}
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    selectedItem: null,
     items: [
     {
         id: 1,
         name: "Dropdown Item"
     },
     {
         id: 2,
         name: "Dropdown Item 2"
     },
     {
         id: 3,
         name: "Dropdown Item 3"
     }
    ]
  },
  method: {
     handleSelectItem(item){
       this.selectedItem = item.name;
       // you can also handle toggle action here manually to open and close dropdown
     }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 37):

Building on Kumar's answer, you can access the event in the handler method by default *as long you do not pass any other parameters*.

However, if you do pass a parameter then it seems you have to pass the event explicitly using `$event`:

```
<button @click="doStuff('whatever', $event)">Do Stuff</button>

...

doStuff(whatever, event) {
    console.log(event.target);
}
```

If you're going to use the event object, it's probably better to pass it explicitly rather than rely on the default.  Or not, depending on your point of view.  It's a toss-up between making things clear or saving on typing!

```
<!-- this works -->
<button @click="doStuff">Do Stuff</button>

<!-- this works too -->    
<button @click="doStuff($event)">Do Stuff</button>

...

doStuff(event) {
    console.log(event.target);
}
```

(I tried these out with Vue 2.6)

Answer (score 10):

you can pass the event to the handler function and access it by **event.target**

```
<div class="dropdown-menu" id="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
 <div class="dropdown-content" v-model="selectedItem">
  <a class="dropdown-item" v-for="item in items" @click="HandlerFunction">
    {{item.name}}
  </a>
 </div>
</div>

var app = new Vue({
 el: '#app',
 data: {
  selectedItem: null,
  items: [
   {
     name: "Dropdown Item"
   },
   {
     name: "Dropdown Item 2"
   },
   {
     name: "Dropdown Item 3"
   }
  ]
 },
 methods: {
  HandlerFunction(event){
   console.log(event.target)
  }
 }
});
```

Comment: note that `event.target` will not be read all the time. Use `event.currentTarget` instead.

Answer (score 4):

We can also use ES6 syntax abbreviation via the methods:

```
... template
<a @click="expand" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false">{{ menuItem.title }}</a>
... more template


... script section
methods: {
    expand({ target }) {
      console.log('this is the element i clicked: ', target);
    }
  }
... more script code
```

Answer (score 1):

thank you i make it with your way just a little different :

```
<a class="dropdown-item" v-model="selectedItem" v-for="item in items" @click="selected(item)">
        {{item.name}}
      </a>


var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    selectedItem: null,
     items: [
     {
         name: "Dropdown Item"
     },
     {
         name: "Dropdown Item 2"
     },
     {
         name: "Dropdown Item 3"
     }
    ]
    },
    methods: {
      selected(element) {
        this.selectedItem = element.name
      }
    }
  });
```